# mysqlprocedure weird mistake on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, character-encoding

I'm trying to change charset of my mysql database using a procedure.

I wrote it few years ago and did not go back to it, till today.

By this I have a weird mistake :

below is my procedure :

```
Create procedure changecharset()
Begin
Declare tname varchar(255);
Declare done int default 0;
Declare tc Cursor For
Select TABLE_NAME From information_schema.TABLES Where TABLE_SCHEMA = schema();
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;

Open tc;
myloop: loop
Fetch tc into tname;
If done = 1 Then
Leave myloop;
End if ;
Set @query = Concat('Alter Table `', tname, '` convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_swedish_ci;');
PREPARE alterstmt FROM @query; 
execute alterstmt ;
Deallocate prepare alterstmt;
End loop;

close tc;
End //

Delimiter ;
[/sql]
```

and this is the answer of mysql server

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '' at line 3

Anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: Some particular reason for `utf8_swedish_ci` instead of the preferred `utf8_unicode_520_ci`?

Comment: The specific language utf8 encoding (such as utf8_swedish_ci) contain additional language rules that make them the most accurate to sort for those languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like MySQL is seeing the semicolon as the end of the statement.

Make sure you change the delimiter before running the CREATE PROCEDURE statement.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE foo()
BEGIN
   DECLARE ... ; 
   SET ... ;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I have a new mistake now 

 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[/sql]' at line 1

Comment: Well the error is now pointing to `[/sql]`.  What is that gibberish?  Not MySQL syntax.

Comment: I have no idea. 4 years ago it worked. Now it does not work.